# Case class difference with field names on matcher failure

Tags: scala, diff, scalatest, pretty-print, case-class

[munit](https://scalameta.org/munit/) out-of-the-box shows pretty diffs on assertion failure for case classes which include field names, for example,

```
class CaseClassPrettyDiffSpec extends munit.FunSuite {
  case class User(name: String, age: Int)

  test("User should be Picard") {
    val expected = User("Picard", 67)
    val actual = User("Worf", 30)
    assertEquals(actual, expected)
  }
}
```

prints

[image]

Are such pretty diffs possible in ScalaTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScalaTest 3.1.0 provides [enhanced prettifier](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/pull/1027) out-of-the-box, for example,

```
import com.softwaremill.diffx.scalatest.DiffMatcher
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class CaseClassPrettyDiffSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  case class User(name: String, age: Int)

  "User" should "be Picard" in {
    val expected = User("Picard", 67)
    val actual = User("Worf", 30)
    actual should be (expected)
  }
}
```

prints `Analysis` section which includes field names but lacks highlighting and formatting

[image]

To get nicer highlighting and formatting we could try [diffx-scalatest](https://github.com/softwaremill/diffx#scalatest-integration), for example,

```
class CaseClassPrettyDiffSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with DiffMatcher {
  case class User(name: String, age: Int)

  "User" should "be Picard" in {
    val expected = User("Picard", 67)
    val actual = User("Worf", 30)
    actual should matchTo(expected)
  }
}
```

prints

[image]