# Scalatest - pretty error messsage outputs?

Tags: scala, scalatest

When using scalatest, any time we have to compare collections of case classes, if one of the parameters is different from expected, the output is unreadable and we have to put it in a notepad and format it correctly in order to figure out what's wrong.

Is there any way to override the default output of scalatest into something more readable?

For example:

```
  case class Test(a: String, b: String, c: String)

  "lists" should "match" in {
    val l1 = List(
      Test("a", "b", "c"),
      Test("d", "e", "f"),
      Test("g", "h", "i")
    )

    val l2 = List(
      Test("a", "b", "c"),
      Test("d", "E", "f"),
      Test("g", "h", "i")
    )

    l1 should contain theSameElementsAs l2
  }
```

output:

```
lists
- should match *** FAILED ***
  List(Test("a", "b", "c"), Test("d", "e", "f"), Test("g", "h", "i")) did not contain the same elements as List(Test("a", "b", "c"), Test("d", "E", "f"), Test("g", "h", "i")) (Test.scala:52)
```

This isn't as bad, since the Test case class isn't too large. But if its a big case class, the output can get very ugly.

What I want is something like this:

```
lists
- should match *** FAILED ***
  List(
    Test("a", "b", "c"),
    Test("d", "e", "f"),
    Test("g", "h", "i")
  )
  did not contain the same elements as
  List(
    Test("a", "b", "c"),
    Test("d", "E", "f"),
    Test("g", "h", "i")
  )
  (Test.scala:52)
```

Even better if I can have it tell me what is different.

Besides switching test frameworks, is this something doable with scalatest?

Comment: Apart from using something like diffx (but still with scalatest), I don't think you can achieve the nice output you want.

Comment: It's easy to get useful output out of ScalaTest. All you need to do is replace ScalaTest with munit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [diffx-scala](https://diffx-scala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test-frameworks/scalatest.html) with ScalaTest:

```
import org.scalatest._
import flatspec._
import com.softwaremill.diffx.scalatest.DiffShouldMatcher._
import com.softwaremill.diffx.generic.AutoDerivation


class ExampleSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with AutoDerivation {

  case class Test(a: String, b: String, c: String)

  "lists" should "match" in {
    val l1 = List(
      Test("a", "b", "c"),
      Test("d", "e", "f"),
      Test("g", "h", "i")
    )

    val l2 = List(
      Test("a", "b", "c"),
      Test("d", "E", "f"),
      Test("g", "h", "i")
    )

    l1 shouldMatchTo(l2)
  }
}
```

which gives pretty printed matching error output:

```
ExampleSpec:
lists
- should match *** FAILED ***
  Matching error:
  List(
       0: Test(
            a: a,
            b: b,
            c: c),
       1: Test(
            a: d,
            b: e -> E,
            c: f),
       2: Test(
            a: g,
            b: h,
            c: i)) (MySuite.scala:34)
Execution took 0.19s
1 tests, 1 failed
```

Related question: [Case class difference with field names on matcher failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025869/case-class-difference-with-field-names-on-matcher-failure)